# Простейший web server с ответом в браузер

Tags: веб-программирование, java

Добрый день, господа!

У меня проблема.
Небоходимо реализовать следующий функционал.

Есть страница с двумя полями, в которые нужно вводить два числа, и с кнопкой, по которой эти два числа должны отправляться на серверную часть, которая должна быть на Java. 
Сервер должен на основе этих двух чисел вычислять ответ и показывать клиенту в браузер.

Я могу написать простейший вэб-сервер, который будет показывать в браузер информацию, но как информацию из полей передать в java программку на сервере, не представляю.

Буду очень благодарен за указание направления, куда копать. Спасибо, что дочитали до конца)

Comment: @despc, зачем писать сервер с нуля? Возьмите tomcat.

Comment: @Etki, поднимать томкат, чтобы обработать один запрос — не тяжеловато ли?

Я для подобных задач обычно использую скрипт в 10 строчек на JRuby + Sinatra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> но как информацию из полей передать в java программку на сервере не представляю

Как это делается повсеместно: через GET или POST-параметры.

Поля на странице обычно привязываются к форме. У формы есть атрибут `method`, указывающий, какой HTTP-метод применять для отправки данных. Предположим, поля формы имеют имена `param1` и `param2`:

- если указан метод `GET`, значения полей уйдут в виде параметров адреса: `http://.......?param1=...&param2=...`. В таком случае вам на стороне сервера нужно будет обратиться к параметру примерно так (зависит от выбранного сервера): `httpRequest.getParameter("param1")`;
- если указан метод `POST`, значения полей будут отправлены в теле `POST`-запроса, упакованные в формат `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` или `multipart/form-data`. Например, `param1=Some+Value&param2=%40`. Вы сможете получить значения, получив тело запроса и расшифровав его. Что-то вроде  `URLDecoder.decode(httpRequest.getRequestBody())`.

Вообще рекомендую для начала разобраться с протоколом HTTP и его методами. Когда придет осознание, что работа с протоколом не зависит от языка и по сути вы обращаетесь к одним и тем же примитивам, искать информацию будет проще.

ЗЫ. Чтобы не заниматься велосипедостроением на примитивных задачах, можно попробовать воспользоваться веб-сервером, встроенным в JVM (это не для серьезного продакшена, разумеется):

```
HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
server.createContext("/", new HttpHandler() {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange httpExchange) throws IOException {
        // тут ваш обработчик запросов
        httpExchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
        httpExchange.close();
    }
});

server.start();
```

Для чего-то серьезного можно взять, например, Jetty - он легко встраивается в любое приложение.

Comment: Спасибо вам за направление. Может, подскажете еще по поводу httpRequest. Я не смог найти именно такой класс, только javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, а это не то, что мне нужно, как я понимаю. Подскажите, при помощи какого класса мне можно вытащить переданные параметры?

Comment: @despc, подскажу, если расскажете, что у вас за веб-сервер.